# Retrieve filtered export using web services for fields with no value

Tags: acumatica

I've got a web service consumer that's using the Project screen to retrieve a list of projects.  I have filters set on certain fields, but the problem is that sometimes those fields don't have values.  I'm using a wildcard to get everything in the following manner (using '%' in my filter value):

```
new Project.Filter
{
    Field = new Project.Field() 
     {   
      ObjectName = _project.GeneralInfoGeneralSettings.ProjectManager.ObjectName,
      FieldName = _project.GeneralInfoGeneralSettings.ProjectManager.FieldName
     },
     Condition = Project.FilterCondition.Contain, 
     Value = sheet.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString(), //'%' for wildcard
     Operator = Project.FilterOperator.And
},
```

Unfortunately, if the field in Acumatica has no value, this filter will not bring back the record.   What's the best way of doing this?

Also - I've noticed there's a 'OpenBrackets' and 'CloseBrackets' in the filter - but I can't find any documentation (including a google search) on how to use these.   Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: why not create a condition wherein it will check first if that field you are referring has a value or null.

Comment: As far as I know - you can't put condition code (if / else) inside of these command arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using this..

```
string.IsNullorEmpty(sheet.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString()) ? "%" : sheet.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that and it wouldn't compile.  I must have had some syntax wrong.

Thanks much!!